# Ошибка сценария при загрузке страницы в TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi-7, delphi, javascript, webbrowser

Поставил компонент `TWebBrowser`, загружаю страницу, выходит ошибка сценария. Если игнорировать ошибки путем

```
WB2.Silent := true;
```

то ошибки нет, но функционал страницы нарушен.

Как устранить данную проблему и сохранить функционал загружаемой страницы?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что никак. Скорее всего, что WebBrowser не поддерживает какие-то объекты или методы, которые использует сценарий.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci а есть какой-нибудь другой компонент, который может с этим справится?

Comment: Если он и есть, то я о нем не знаю. WebBrowser разрабатывался более 10 лет назад. А стандарты Web меняются со скоростью света.

Comment: Грусть( Чтож, @kot-da-vinci спасибо, буду гуглить и пытаться найти решение)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, Вы случайно не знакомы с jsWebbrowser? Может ли он помочь выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: Зачем вам delphi-7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать проект DCEF3 TChromium https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3, что бы избежать подобных проблем (на данный момент доступна ветка https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3/tree/2924).